# How do I round an input variable to a certain number

Tags: python-3.5

I am using python 3+ and I want to round a variable up to 500 and if the input is higher than 500 then it rounds up to 1000. Is there a way I could math.ceil() or round() ?
I have done this so far but I'm not sure whether I have come across it in the right way.

```
import math
x = int(input("how much data did you use this month? "))
math.ceil(x / 500.0) * 500.0
print(x)
```

I want to round x up to 500 whatever the number is but if it is higher (e.g - 600) I want it to round it to 1000. The last line does not work and only prints what the user inputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

math.ceil() returns the value that you expect but you haven't assignet it to anything.
Simply assign that value to your variable.

This is the solution:

```
 import math
 x = int(input("how much data did you use this month? "))
 x = math.ceil(x / 500.0) * 500.0

 print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
x = math.ceil(x / 500.0) * 500.0
```

to update your x variable before printing your x variable?